# How data is stored in MongoDB tables?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm learning Mongodb by integrating it with my Java application. Till now I have configured my MongoDB as a Windows service that runs when my windows starts and also I'm successfully able to connect, insert and finding data from MongoDB which is integrated with my Java application. I understand that each data is stored as a Key:Document pair in MongoDb and scaled horizontally without any predefined schema definition. However I'm still not clear with my following doubts:-

1) When we say each data is stored as key:document pair then what does the term 'key' here means? Is it primary value which I'm entering in the data or does this 'key' means some unique record id (containing random numbers like in RDBMS). For instance:-

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("employee");
        BasicDBObject document = document = new BasicDBObject();
        document.put("EmpId", "1001");
        document.put("Name", "Vijay Kumar");
        document.put("Gender", "Male");
        table.insert(document);
```

Here, if I'm not wrong then EmpId is not the key here, right? Key will be unique id of this data in MongoDB table called 'employee' like '57cd9d404a85c209a42ed747'. Please confirm.

2) When we say each data is stored as a document then what exactly it means? How it looks like, in a structured form or unstructured? Can't we see the stored documents using some client like SQLDeveloper or Toad for RDBMS?

3) Finally which is faster to store as well to retrieve with huge data

Comment: Mongo will create a unique id field for you, and the data is stored as Binary JSON (BSON).

Comment: Just a side-note: if you are just starting out with MongoDB, I assume that you use a current version. If that is the case, please search for a current tutorial, which does NOT use the old API anymore. As of 3.2 you should aim for use of MongoClient / MongoDatabase / MongoCollection / org.bson.Document. A good place to start is here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/reference/crud/

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB creates a unique id to refer to a particular document in a table.

For 1:

> The key you are talkng about here is a reference variable to pick a
>   data whenever it is called. So we say `key-value pair`. So `EmpId` is
>   the key and `1001` is the value. Or you can view the key as the name
>   of the column in a table and `1001` as a field.

For 2:

> The document is a collection of key-value pair. For example:

```
{
    "EmpId", "1001",
    "Name", "Vijay Kumar"
}
```

This can be considered as one document.

For 3:

> To store huge data, you need to store the documents in an array form.
>   for example you can use `JSONArray object`

For eaxmple:

```
[
    {
        "EmpId", "1001",
        "Name", "Vijay Kumar"
    },
    {
        "EmpId", "1002",
        "Name", "Emil John"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically the data stores in Mongodb as Binary JSON and for every  document inserted it creates a unique id (default name  _id) . Now when you compare it to traditional RDBMS, consider key as column and value as its data. So each document actually means a particular row of a relational Database and collection means a Table.

There are few tools for MongoDB . I particularly use MongoChef.

Mongodb is design to handle huge data so it is faster than Traditional RDBMS when it comes to retrieving and storing the data.